# Нужно создать декоратор для проверки размера матриц (списка из списков)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, декоратор, bool

Не получается реализовать декоратор check_size проверки формы матриц (списков из списков из float). Необходимо, чтобы функция инициализации объекта матрицы (create_matrix) с декоратором возвращала False, если число элементов всех внутренних списков разное и True в противном случае.

```
def check_size(a):
    # редактировать тут, ниже мои попытки
    prov=True
    for i in a:
        if len(a[i])!=len(a[i+1]):
            prov = False
            break
    return prov

@check_size
def create_matrix(a):
    # здесь тоже надо что-то изменить
    matrix = a

print(create_matrix(a))
```

Comment: Начать надо с того, что декоратор - функция высшего порядка, которая принимает функцию как аргумент и возвращает функцию.

Comment: Не очень понятно, а что должна делать сама функция create_matrix? Судя по названию - создавать матрицу, но что конкретно под этим подразумевается? И почему проверку надо выносить именно в декоратор, если конечная задача - возвращать True или False в зависимости от результатов проверки? Кажется, декоратор тут вообще ни к чему. Вы можете привести точную формулировку задания?

Comment: на самом деле текст вопроса это и есть, с точностью кроме первых двух слов, скопированная формулировка задания

Comment: мне вот тоже не сильно понятно, а зачем здесь декоратор, ведь проверку можно осуществлять и внутри самой функции. Но видимо такой они пример для отработки темы подобрали

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, если вы уверены, что формулировка задания именно такая, то вот код, который делает именно то, что требуется:

```
def check_size(func):
    def wrapper(a):
        # Вычисляем множество длинн всех строк матрицы
        # Если все строки одной длинны, то в множестве будет только один элемент
        sizes = {len(row) for row in a}
        func(a)
        # Проверяем, что в множестве действительно только один элемент
        return len(sizes) == 1
    return wrapper


@check_size
def create_matrix(a):
    # Здесь должно быть собственно создание/ инициализация матрицы
    # Но из задания вообще не понятно, что под этим подразумевается
    # Впрочем, для демонстрации работы декоратора это и не важно
    # Поэтому оставляю так
    matrix = a

# Проверяем

# Правильная матрица
good_matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

print(create_matrix(good_matrix))  # Напечатает True

# Неправильная матрица
bad_matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]

print(create_matrix(bad_matrix))  # Напечатает False
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Не додумалась я воспользоваться множествами, но теперь всё понятно. Решение приняли

Comment: Пожалуйста. Если ответ вам помог, вы можете плюсануть его или отметить его как решение. Для этого служат галочка и треугольник остриём вверх слева от ответа.